# How to verify JWT Access Token from Azure AD in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure-active-directory, jwt

I am trying desperately to verify a JWT access token from Azure AD.

The error being raised is `JWT::VerificationError (Signature verification raised)`

Here is my code below in it's entirety edited to run as a script so it can be copy/pasted into a terminal. It is based on the Auth0 implementation.

The constant MY_SUPER_SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN needs to be set to an access token from Azure AD.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

access_token = MY_SUPER_SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN

jwks_raw = Net::HTTP.get URI('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys')

jwks_hash = Hash[
      jwks_keys
      .map do |k|
        [
          k['kid'],
          OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(
            Base64.decode64(k['x5c'].first)
          ).public_key
        ]
      end
    ]

token_info = JWT.decode(access_token, nil, false, {algorithm: 'RS256'})

cert_public_key = jwks_hash[token_info[1]['kid']]

JWT.decode(access_token, cert_public_key, true, algorithms: 'RS256')
```

This raises a Signature error? I'm not super great at any of this and we were using Auth0 with a very similar setup.

Is there some obvious fundamental step that I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: You should start by reading the Ruby JWT documentation. [Here](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt#json-web-key-jwk) you can find the preferred `kid` verification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow up to this question, here is where the docs aren't very clear.

MS uses a different interpretation of what information and what role `id` and `access` tokens take compared to a standard oauth.

The reason I could not validated any **access** tokens, is those are signed by MS and are only supposed to be used to validate access to MS apis. They will not be any good for validation authentication to your API.

That is also why an ID token does validate, in that it is signed by your app and can be used to authenticate against your own API.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to verify a JWT from Azure with the following. Also could look at using a solution suggested [here](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt/issues/370)

```
id_token # issuer https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/v2.0

jwks = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get URI('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys'))

JWT.decode(id_token, nil, true, { algorithms: ['RS256'], jwks: jwks})
```

Comment: Yes, this works with the ID token. The link you supplied looks promising as the access token can be validated on the MS token validator but JWT.io is unable to.